# i have 3 textboxes in gridview. When value is entered to first and second textboxes i want automatically write result to third textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have 3 textboxes in gridview. When value is entered to first and second textboxes i want automatically write result to third textbox.

this is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="892px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ales Puanı">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ales" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("alesSinavPuani") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dil Puanı">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Dil" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("dilSinavPuani") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Toplam">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Toplam" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Mention AutoPostBack="true" for 2 textbox's
2) Mention event OnTextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" for 2 textbox's
3) In TextChanged Event access the controls, find the result logic and assign to the 3rd control. In this case, 3rd control is mentioned as Label. It can be Textbox also.

ASPX Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="3" Width="892px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ales Puanı">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Ales" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("alesSinavPuani") %>' OnTextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dil Puanı">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Dil" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("dilSinavPuani") %>'  OnTextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Toplam">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Toplam" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

TextChange Event Code

```
 protected void Txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox Txt_Ales = GridView1.Rows[((sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex].FindControl("Txt_Ales") as TextBox;
            TextBox txt_Dil = GridView1.Rows[((sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Dil") as TextBox;
            Label lbl_Toplam = GridView1.Rows[((sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_Toplam") as Label;

            int num1, num2 = 0;
            if (Txt_Ales != null && txt_Dil != null && lbl_Toplam != null)
            {
                int.TryParse(Txt_Ales.Text, out num1);
                int.TryParse(txt_Dil.Text, out num2);
                lbl_Toplam.Text = (num1 + num2).ToString();
            }
        }
```